# Create Index for specific value in mysql column

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a column in my table with `TinyInt` type, which stores millions of numbers ranging from 0 to 50.

However a great proportion of them have the exact value of  `50`.

Now I need to set an index to split 50s and non 50s. I have already a BTREE index but it is not used in queries like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE num != 50
```

I think a BTREE index is useful for range indexes. But I need an index for an exact value only.

Comment: Use partitioning. Or at least test `.. WHERE num < 50`. Also you may try to force the index usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OPTION #1

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX mycolumn_index (mycolumn);
```

Then, just run this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE num < 50;
```

IMHO it would produce a very lopsided index because of the majority of the values being 50. It would just be a waste of space.

### OPTION #2 : Partition the table

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
PARTITION BY RANGE (mycolumn) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (51),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

What does this produce ???

- All rows with mycolumn < 50 land in partition p0.
- All rows with mycolumn = 50 land in partition p1.
- All rows with mycolumn > 50 land in partition p2.

Partition p2 would never grow if you never enter data with values > 50. Otherwise, that partition will have 0 rows and may occupy like 4K at best.

Then you could run the SELECT against all the non-50 values like this

```
SELECT * FROM employees PARTITION (p0);
```

This would be a very quick table scan on just that partition.

This query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE num < 50;
```

would still work just as well with an index.

Comment: ("num" vs "mycolumn" -- Please be consistent.)